# Nginx with multiple thread FCGI

Tags: multithreading, nginx, fastcgi

Could you help me explain my situation using Nginx:

1. Nginx config:

   ```
   worker_processes 1;
   worker_rlimit_nofile 1000;

   // ...

   worker_connections  1024;
       multi_accept on;
       use epoll;

   location /test_nginx {
       module_test_nginx;
   }


   location /test_fcgi {
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
       include fastcgi_params;
   }
   ```
2. module_test_nginx is my module that sleep few seconds if request having parameter then return "Hello World"

   I make 2 concurrent connections (1 from FireFox, 1 from Chrome)

> 1st request from FireFox: localhost/test_nginx?sleep=5 -> the browser
>   display "Hello World" after 5 seconds
>
> 2nd request from Chrome: localhost/test_nginx?sleep=1 -> the
>   browser display "Hello World" after 5 seconds waitting for 1st request and 1 second as sleep parameter

I changed worker_processes to 2, then:

> 1st request from FireFox: localhost/test_nginx?sleep=5 -> the
>   browser display "Hello World" after 5 seconds
>
> 2nd request from Chrome: localhost/test_nginx?sleep=1 -> the
>   browser display "Hello World" after 1 second while FireFox still loading

This testing show me that module_test_nginx blocked the 2nd request until 1st has been finished.

3. I write "Hello World" Fcgi program that is similar to module_test_nginx but having 2 threads in pool (I run it using spawn-fcgi, port 8080)

   I set worker_processes = 1, then:

> 1st request from FireFox: localhost/test_fcgi?sleep=5 -> the
>   browser display "Hello World" after 5 seconds
>
> 2nd request from Chrome: localhost/test_fcgi?sleep=1 -> the browser
>   display "Hello World" after 1 second (while FireFox is still loading)

So I think Nginx with fastcgi_pass can serve more clients than Nginx with module_test_nginx

4. I make some loading test with: ab, siege with the same concurrent connections, total connections...
   Url 1 on FireFox: localhost/test_nginx
   Url 2 on Chrome: localhost/test_fcgi
   Both of two links return immediately, no sleeping. 
   But all testing show me that Nginx with module_test_nginx result better request per second rate than Nginx with fastcgi_pass (more than 3 or 4 times)

Thanks for reading and please help me explain :)